# Finding the global minimum of the multivariable function using only algebraic tools

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, proof-writing, maxima-minima

**Problem says:**

> Find the global minimum of
>
> $$\begin{align}f(x,y): &= x^2 + y^2 + \alpha xy + x + 2y\end{align}$$
>
> where, $\alpha\in\mathbb R$.

---

The things I have done:

Let,

$$f(x,y):=x^2+x(\alpha y+1)+2y+y^2$$

- Algebraic tool I will use along the way:

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-m)^2+n$$

$$m=-\frac{b}{2a},~n=-\frac{\Delta}{4a}$$

---

In this case, we have

$$\begin{align}m:&=-\frac{\alpha y+1}{2} \\
 n:&=\frac 14 \left(y^2(4-\alpha ^2) + 2y(4-
\alpha)-1\right)&\end{align}$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}f(x,y):=\left(x+\frac{\alpha y+1}{2}\right)^2+\frac 14 \left(y^2(4-\alpha ^2) + 2y(4-\alpha)-1\right)\end{align}$$

If $\alpha =±2$ , putting

$$x=-\frac{\alpha y+1}{2}$$

we get

$$f(x,y):=\frac{y(4-\alpha)}{2}-\frac 14$$

Since $4-\alpha>0$ for $\alpha=±2$, we observe that the lower bound of  $\frac{y(4-\alpha)}{2}-\frac 14$ doesn't exist (applying $y\to -\infty$).

If $|\alpha|>2$, then applying the same method, we have

$$\begin{align}\frac 14 \left(y^2(4-\alpha ^2) + 2y(4-\alpha)-1\right)=y^2\left(1-\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}\right)+y\left(2-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)-\frac 14=\left(1-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}\right)\left(y+\frac{4-\alpha}{4-\alpha ^2}\right)^2+\frac{2 \alpha - 5}{4 - \alpha^2}\end{align}$$

So, we obtain

$$\begin{align}f(x,y):=\left(x+\frac{\alpha y+1}{2}\right)^2+\left(1-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}\right)\left(y+\frac{4-\alpha}{4-\alpha ^2}\right)^2+\frac{2 \alpha - 5}{4 - \alpha^2}\end{align}$$

Likewise, if $|\alpha|>2$ then putting $$x=-\frac{\alpha y+1}{2}$$ we get,

$$\begin{align}f(x,y):=\left(1-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}\right)\left(y+\frac{4-\alpha}{4-\alpha ^2}\right)^2+\frac{2 \alpha - 5}{4 - \alpha^2}\end{align}$$

Observing that,

$$1-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}<0$$ where $|\alpha|>2$. This means, if $|\alpha|>2$, then the lower bound of
$$\begin{align}\left(1-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}\right)\left(y+\frac{4-\alpha}{4-\alpha ^2}\right)^2+\frac{2 \alpha - 5}{4 - \alpha^2}\end{align}$$

doesn't exist. (applying $y\to +\infty$)

Finally, if $|\alpha|<2\iff -2<\alpha<2$, then $1-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}>0$ and putting

$$x=-\frac{\alpha y+1}{2}, ~~y=\frac{\alpha-4}{4- \alpha^2}$$

in the original function

$$\begin{align}f(x,y):=\left(x+\frac{\alpha y+1}{2}\right)^2+\left(1-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}\right)\left(y+\frac{4-\alpha}{4-\alpha ^2}\right)^2+\frac{2 \alpha - 5}{4 - \alpha^2}\end{align}$$

we conclude

$$\begin{align}\min \left\{x^2 + y^2 + \alpha xy + x + 2y {\large{\mid}} -2<\alpha<2\right\}=\frac{2\alpha-5}{4-\alpha^2} ~\text {at}~ x=\frac{2-2\alpha}{\alpha^2-4} ~\text{and}~ y=\frac{\alpha-4}{4- \alpha^2}. \end{align}$$

---

Questions:

- Is the algebraic method I use rigorous enough?  Are there still non-rigorous points in my steps?
- What I'm doing is just finding the minimum of the given function.  How can I show that the minimum I found is a global minimum?

Thank you for reviewing.

Comment: Your statements are true, but there are some false / unsubstantiated claims. EG Simply showing that $ f(x,y) > g(y)$, and seeing that $g(y)$ doesn't have a lower bound doesn't imply that $f(x,y)$ doesn't have a lower bound.  Do you see what logical step you're missing out / didn't make explicit?

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for comment. I'm a little confused.  I think your comment.  I am trying to understand.

Comment: (slight personal preference) To show that $f(x,y) $ is unbounded below for $ |\alpha | \geq 2$, you should do it explicity. EG For $ \alpha \geq 2$, take $ x = n, y = -n, n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Now, I got it your first comment. This is unnecessary $$\begin{align}f(x,y)&≥y^2\left(1-\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}\right)+y\left(2-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)-\frac 14\end{align}$$

Comment: To elaborate on my first point, consider the explicit example of $ f(x,y) = 0$ and $g(y) = - y^2$. Clearly, we have $f(x,y) \geq g (y)$. Using (my interpretation of) your logic, since $g(y)$ does not have a minimum, hence $f(x,y)$ does not have a minimum.   $\quad \quad$ To be clear, my interpretation of your logic might be incorrect, but that is because you have an unstated assumption/fact/observation going on which makes the result true.

Comment: @CalvinLin No, I understand your points. Very true.

Comment: (Yes, we posted at the same-ish time.)

Comment: @CalvinLin I could not have noticed this sensitive point myself.  You found/showed it very nice.  I'll fix that part now.  But since the $\alpha=±2, y\to -\infty$ parts are clear, I didn't add it to the solution.  Should I add these?

Comment: @CalvinLin But if I do so, any of your answer could be invalid.  If you want to give an answer, I will not edit my question and I will accept your answer. Thank you.!

Comment: 1) Without seeing your edits, i don't know why the $\alpha = \pm2$ parts are clear. 2) Just go ahead and edit your question. I can delete my comments. If you want to accept an answer, I can post that the solution is fine after the fixes.

Comment: near the end, there is the equation $$y=\frac{\alpha-4}{4-\alpha^2}$$ Is that supposed to be $m=\dots$ or something?

Comment: @robjohn What is $m$? I could not get the point

Comment: as in $m=-\frac{b}{2a},~n=-\frac{\Delta}{4a}$. You've set $x=-\frac{\alpha y+1}{2}$ (a function of $y$), now if you set $y=\frac{\alpha-4}{4-\alpha^2}$, we are only looking at a single point.

Comment: The person who downvoted after a long time, if your heart is enough, write a comment?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few difficulties in figuring out what is meant in the given solution.

A tool is given
$$
ax^2+bx+c=a(x-m)^2+n
$$
$$
m=-\frac{b}{2a},~n=-\frac{\Delta}{4a}
$$
It is left to the reader to figure out that $\Delta=b^2-4ac$. It was not clear to me, at first, that this would be used on the previous line
$$
f(x,y):=\!\!\!\!\overset{\substack{a=1\\\downarrow}}{\vphantom{\sum}}\!\!\!\!x^2+x\overbrace{(\alpha y+1)\vphantom{y^2}}^b+\overbrace{\ 2y+y^2\ }^c
$$
For an exposition, it would be nice to `\tag` these lines and reference them as they are used.

1. Other than a typo or two, I think the method is sound.
2. When $|\alpha|\lt2$, the equation has been reduced to a square plus a constant. The square is minimized at $0$. What else needs to be shown?

---

That being said, here is how I would proceed.

Expand
$$
\begin{align}
&(x+dy+e)^2+(y+dx+f)^2\\[6pt]
&=\left(1+d^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2\right)+4dxy+2(e+df)x+2(f+de)y+e^2+f^2\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Since
$$
d=\frac{2-\sqrt{4-a^2}}a\implies\frac{4d}{1+d^2}=a\tag2
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{(x+dy+e)^2+(y+dx+f)^2}{1+d^2}\\[6pt]
&=x^2+y^2+axy+\frac{2(e+df)}{1+d^2}x+\frac{2(f+de)}{1+d^2}y+\frac{e^2+f^2}{1+d^2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Since
$$
\left.
\begin{array}{}
\displaystyle e=\frac{b-cd}2\frac{1+d^2}{1-d^2}\\
\displaystyle f=\frac{c-bd}2\frac{1+d^2}{1-d^2}
\end{array}
\right\}\implies
\left\{
\begin{array}{}
\displaystyle \frac{2(e+df)}{1+d^2}=b\\
\displaystyle \frac{2(f+de)}{1+d^2}=c\\
\displaystyle \frac{e^2+f^2}{1+d^2}=\frac{b^2+c^2-abc}{4-a^2}
\end{array}
\right.\tag4
$$
we have
$$
\frac{(x+dy+e)^2+(y+dx+f)^2}{1+d^2}=x^2+y^2+axy+bx+cy+\frac{b^2+c^2-abc}{4-a^2}\tag5
$$
Therefore,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x^2+y^2+axy+bx+cy\ge\frac{abc-b^2-c^2}{4-a^2}}\tag6
$$
where equality is achieved at
$$
\begin{align}
x
&=\frac{fd-e}{1-d^2}\tag{7a}\\
&=\frac{2cd-b\left(1+d^2\right)}{2\left(1-d^2\right)}\frac{1+d^2}{1-d^2}\tag{7b}\\
&=\frac{ac-2b}{4}\left(\frac{1+d^2}{1-d^2}\right)^2\tag{7c}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{ac-2b}{4-a^2}\tag{7d}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
y
&=\frac{de-f}{1-d^2}\tag{8a}\\
&=\frac{2bd-c\left(1+d^2\right)}{2\left(1-d^2\right)}\frac{1+d^2}{1-d^2}\tag{8b}\\
&=\frac{ab-2c}{4}\left(\frac{1+d^2}{1-d^2}\right)^2\tag{8c}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{ab-2c}{4-a^2}\tag{8d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(7a) and (8a)}$: set the left side of $(5)$ to $0$ and solve
$\text{(7b) and (8b)}$: apply the left side of $(4)$
$\text{(7c) and (8c)}$: apply the right side of $(2)$
$\text{(7d) and (8d)}$: the right side of $(2)$ says that $4-a^2=4\left(\frac{1-d^2}{1+d^2}\right)^2$

---

**Case $\boldsymbol{|a|\lt2}$**

Applying $(6)$ to this question for $|a|\lt2$ gives a global minimum of
$$
x^2+y^2+axy+bx+cy\ge\frac{abc-b^2-c^2}{4-a^2}=\frac{2a-5}{4-a^2}\tag9
$$
**Case $\boldsymbol{|a|\ge2}$**

If $|a|\ge2$, then along the line $y=-\frac2ax$,
$$
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2+axy+bx+cy
&=\left(x+\frac a2y\right)^2-\left(\frac{a^2}4-1\right)y^2+bx+cy\tag{10a}\\
&=-\frac{a^2-4}{a^2}x^2+\left(b-\frac{2c}a\right)x\tag{10b}
\end{align}
$$
which, if $|a|\gt2$, tends to $-\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

If $|a|=2$ and $b\ne\frac{2c}a$ (as in the question), $\text{(10b)}$ is also unbounded below.

If $|a|=2$ and $b=\frac{2c}a$, then $x^2+y^2+axy+bx+cy=0$.

Comment: Thank you!. I am so grateful for your time.I should have explained them at first.  You are right. Can you elaborate your point -2 a little bit?  What do you mean by typing error?(I am refer your point -1) Please can you change the word "sound" with its alternative? Google'da translate was stuck.

Comment: Re point 1: Perhaps I am misunderstanding what is going on in your analysis of the case $|\alpha|\lt2$. It seems as if you are looking at a single point since you've set $x=-\frac{\alpha y+1}{2}$ and $y=\frac{\alpha-4}{4-\alpha^2}$. If you are using that point in some earlier formula, it is not obvious. That is why I suggested tagging and referencing the lines of your answer.

Comment: Re point 2: in your analysis of $|\alpha|\lt2$, you have written $x^2+y^2+axy+x+2y$ as a square of a function plus a constant. The function that is squared has only one point where it is $0$. This shows there is only one minimum point.

Comment: Your second point shows that the minimum is the global minimum, do I get it right?(answer to my second question, in my solution)

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Another approach is to include $f(x,y)$ in the quadratic class as

$$
f(x,y) = (x-x_0,y-y_0)'M(x-x_0,y-y_0)+c
$$

Choosing $M = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \frac{\alpha }{2} \\
 \frac{\alpha }{2} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and equating coefficients we arrive at

$$
\cases{
x_0 = -\frac{2 (\alpha -1)}{\alpha ^2-4}\\
y_0 = \frac{4-\alpha }{\alpha ^2-4}\\
c = \frac{5-2 \alpha }{\alpha ^2-4}
}
$$

and now follow the considerations about $M(\alpha)$ avoiding the case with $\alpha = \pm 2$